# jQuery and outlook style navigation bar plug-in

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui

We are planning to migrate our asp.net forms application into MVC. we are currently using the outlook style navigation using [this](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/12/creating_an_outlook_navigation.html) (asp controls like listview and accordion)
Is there any control (jQuery/CSS) similar to that I can use for MVC?

Answer (score 2):

The [jQuery Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) would be ideal for you...

Comment: I looked into that but that scrolls the menu item above instead of keeping them together at bottom. e.g if I have 5 items and click on 3rd one, it will leave two up, two bottom and expands the 3rd in the middle. I want it to be same like Outlook where the main navigation stays at bottom and grouping appears on the top.

Comment: Yes, we need something purely Javascript/CSS based . No dependencies upon asp.net controls

Comment: Hmmm... I'll scout around and see if I can find something to suit your needs. Maybe a modification to the Accordion would work... @Matt: As he mentioned, he wants to move AWAY from the .NET control.

Comment: thanks, been searching for exactly this type of menu since over an hour!

Comment: Pleasure! Glad it helped you out.